# Azure Api Management get bearer token for Reports - List By Request

Tags: azure, token

I have already created an application that hits the link
" GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/reports/byRequest?$filter={$filter}&api-version=2022-08-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/%7BserviceName%7D/reports/byRequest?$filter=%7B$filter%7D&api-version=2022-08-01) "

provided by Microsoft in the try out link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/reports/list-by-request?tabs=HTTP)

In this link, after we sign in with our Azure credentials and add our `subscriptionid` + resource names and filter, we can get information about our API calls etc.

The problem that I face is that there after we sign in, it gives us a bearer token that can be used also to my application to bring those data. But I cannot find a way to take this bearer token programmatically without having to do the sign in. Is there such a way?

I tried to ask chatgpt, I tried also from postman some post links with client credentials but the bearer token that I took back and used gave me a response of unauthenticated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add **`user_impersonation`** permission to the registered app in Azure Entra ID.

[image]

[image]

***You can generate the Bearer token as shown below-***

Add `resource: https://management.azure.com/`

[image]

Access the API `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/reports/byRequest?$filter={$filter}&api-version=2022-08-01` using the above generated token.

[image]

Comment: I have already seen this answer in a similar post. I have added user_impersonation and I used the above methodology but the bearer token that I took as a response from postman gave me back unauthenticated response. So it did not work unfortunaltely.

Comment: have you added `resource` while generating token?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of token generation?

Comment: Sure, I just added in the question, because I didnt know how to insert it in comments section.

Comment: Ok ok, I am not sure why but now it worked from my app too. Maybe I was typing wrong access token. Thank you very much Afrin!

Comment: Glad it worked.